# Reference for invariant basis number (IBN) rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra

I'm looking for a standard Algebra reference (hopefully a textbook), that I can cite for a discussion of the following:

1. Invariant basis number (IBN) rings
2. The fact: "Any commutative ring is an invariant basis number ring"
3. The fact: "Any finitely generated free module over an invariant basis number ring has an unique dimension given by the size of any (hence all) basis."

3 is essentially the definition of an IBN ring. I'm new to the field of algebra, and have been reading Serge Lang's "Algebra" textbook and Brown's "Matrices over commutative rings" textbook, for over a week. From various internet references such as lecture notes and answers on MathOverflow and Math Stackexchange, I have found that I need to use some well-known facts about IBN rings (especially points 2,3), but I'd like a more standard reference to cite in a paper that I'm writing, where the need to look into these things arose. I cannot locate such a reference easily, so I'd really appreciate if someone more knowledgable in Algebra can point me in the right direction. Lang's and Brown's textbooks does not seem to discuss these it seems.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Chapter 1, section 1, subsection 1A of

> Lam, Tsit-Yuen. Lectures on modules and rings. Vol. 189. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

It's pages 2-5, and covers everything you mentioned.

A google books search also returns page 78 of

> Rowen, Louis Halle. Graduate Algebra: Noncommutative View: Noncommutative View. Vol. 2. American Mathematical Soc., 2008.

And page 60 of

> Rotman, Joseph J. An introduction to homological algebra. Vol. 2. New York: Springer, 2009.

Page 430 of

> Faith, Carl. Algebra: rings, modules and categories I. Vol. 190. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

among others

Comment: Incidentally, [DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/44/) often has information like this on the property pages.

Comment: this is amazing. thanks!